# Exercício JavaScript calculadora simples

Tags: javascript, html

Fala galera, to treinando alguns exercícios de JS e to tentando montar uma calculadora bem simples, mas meu código JS não tá pegando os valores do input e exibindo o resultado na calculadora que coloquei como imagem. Já testei com input ao invés de button no html, tbm tentei usar o .onclick no código JS ao invés de addEventListener, mas nada funcionou. Oq q tá errado nesse código, me ajudem
Segue o html e o js q fiz

```
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <title>Basic Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="op">Operação</h1>
    <section>
        <img src="style/calculator.png" alt="">
    </section>
    <section class="sec1">
        <div class="input-div">
            <input id="a" type="number" placeholder="Insira o primeiro número">
            <input id="b" type="number" placeholder="Insira o segundo número">
        </div>
        <div class="btn-div">
            <button id="sum">Soma</button>
            <button id="sub">Subtração</button>
            <button id="mult">Multiplicação</button>
            <button id="div">Divisão</button>
            <button id="pot">Potência</button>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');
var valor1 = a.value
var valor2 = b.value

function SUM(valor1,valor2){
    var soma = valor1 + valor2
    document.getElementById('op').innerText = soma
    console.log(soma)
}
const btnSum = document.getElementById('sum')
btnSum.addEventListener('click',SUM)
```

Answer (score -2):

Não funciona porque você captura os valores de a e b quando a página é carregada e não atualiza seus valores quando a função de soma é chamada, acredito que é só realizar essa mudança que irá funcionar:

```
function SUM(valor1,valor2){
    var a = document.getElementById('a');
    var b = document.getElementById('b');
    var valor1 = a.value
    var valor2 = b.value
        
    var soma = valor1 + valor2
    document.getElementById('op').innerText = soma
    console.log(soma)
}
const btnSum = document.getElementById('sum')
btnSum.addEventListener('click',SUM)
```